Generalisation of Paley–Wiener type results for unbounded sets
Do you know an unbounded open set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, $d\geq 2$ with the following property: if some integrable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ has its Fourier transform vanishing on $A^c$ and all the derivatives of $f$ exist and vanish at some point, then $f=0$?
It works if $A$ is bounded because then $f$ is holomorphic, hence determined by its derivatives at some point.
To sum up: can I weaken the assumption that $A$ is bounded in the direct sense of the Paley–Wiener theorem if I agree that $A$ is "only" real analytic, not necessarily holomorphic? Ideally I am looking to apply it to tempered distributions.
If not possible, what decay assumption should I add on $f$ to make it possible?

I am pretty sure that for $A = [0, +\infty)$ it doesn't hold, the function is analytic in the lower half-plane, but not up to the boundary. If you are willing to assume additionally that $f$ is in $L^2$, say, then I can construct such unbounded sets.

Indded, I forgot this assumption sorry, I modified the post accordingly.

I also relaxed the regularity assumption, I essentially need that f has a deep zero at some point.

"On the real line, it works with $A = [0, +\infty)$ if $f$ is in $L^2$" -- again, I am pretty sure that this is just false. My idea was that if $A$ is extremely thin, and $f\in L^2(A)$ then $\hat{f}$ is still an entire function, hence you can use the uniqueness theorem, but I don't know if this is the type of result you are interested in?

When $A=(0,\infty)$, your assumption becomes $f\in H^2$. Such functions can indeed not be too small too frequently, but the precise condition is $\int\log |f|>-\infty$ (on the unit circle). That still seems to leave room for all derivatives vanishing at a point (for example, if $|f|\simeq e^{-|x|^{-1/2}}$), confirming Aleksei's comment.

Aleksei: I think we agree: it is good if $\hat f$ vanishes on the complement of the real line, so in particular if it vanishes on the complement on a thin set $A$. I am looking for such unbounded sets $A$ in higher dimensions.
@ChristianRemling: I read on the wikipedia page of the Paley Wiener theorem that $\hat f$ is entire on the upper half plane, but from what you are saying I imagine it is not entire anymore on the boundary...
Too bad for me, I should not have put this example on the real line, I removed it. The question still stands...

@AlekseiKulikov: you said you can construct such examples if $f$ is in $L^2$, I would very much like to know what you have in mind.

I am not sure if this is the sort of thing you want, but here it goes anyway.
The idea is that if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $A$ is very thin then by the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality $f$ is an entire function, thus if the derivatives vanish at some point, then $f$ is identically $0$.
Indeed, we have $f(z) = \int_A \hat{f}(x)e^{2\pi i x\cdot z}dx$, which by the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality is bounded by
$$
\|f\|_{L^2} \left(\int_A e^{-4 \pi Im(x\cdot z)}dx\right)^{1/2} \le \|f\|_{L^2} \left(\int_A e^{4 \pi |x||z|}dx\right)^{1/2}.$$
So, if the set $A$ is super-exponentially thin, meaning that $|(A\cap (B(0, 2R)\backslash B(0, R))|$ decays faster than any exponential in $R$ (here $B(0, r)$ is the ball with center at $0$ and radius $r$), then the integral converges for all $z$, you can differentiate under the integral sign, hence the function is entire and you have uniqueness if all derivatives at some point are $0$.
For example, you can consider the set
$$
A = \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid k < |x| < k + \frac{1}{k!}\,\, \text{for some}\,\, k\in\mathbb{N}\right\}.
$$

Thanks, it is indeed what I am looking for. I am not asking you necessarily to do it, but do you think there is a way to have bigger sets by optimizing this procedure? On the real line one can do better? And also what can we obtained if we have stronger decay assumptions on $f$? I thought there could be a line of literature on this topic.
